# bringing zip file from github to packer machine

Tags: github-actions, packer

I have a 285 MB zip file in github. I want to download this ZIP file to packer machine while running packer build and install it.
is it possible?

My view is: It will not work unless we authenticate to GitHub from the packer machine because that zip file will be hosted in a private/internal repo.

so how do we achieve this?